# Changing boolean text in workflow email

Tags: 2010, workflow, email

I have a list with some boolean (yes/no) columns that are included in an email that is sent by a workflow.  The fields appear as true/false when the email is sent, but I would rather see yes/no.

I could create extra text columns and have them set to "Yes" or "No" in the workflow, but there has to be an easier and better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direct would to use a variable (text or even Boolean) in the workflow whose value you could set according to the field value. Than use that particular variable in the mail message.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/use-variables-in-workflows-HA010240415.aspx#BM1